# Rails Form input_html not working for calling javascipt controller

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

So I have this input field, using form Rails 7.0.2.3, and  I'm looking forward to call a controller but this is not connecting.

```
<%= form_with url: "/projects/#{@project.id}", method: :get do |form| %>
   <%= form.text_field :query, html5: true, input_html: { data: { controller: "flatpickr" } } %>
   <%= form.submit '', class: 'button' %>
<% end %>
```

If I put in the next way, it works, but I need it to be in the input field.
I'm guessing the problem is with ***`input_html`*** tag

```
<%= form_with url: "/projects/#{@project.id}", method: :get do |form| %>
   <div data-controller="flatpickr">
     <%= form.text_field :query %>
   </div>
   <%= form.submit '', class: 'button' %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `text_field` write just

```rb
<%= form.text_field :query, html5: true, data: { controller: "flatpickr" } %>
```

Without `input_html`

Comment: Beautiful, it worked, Thanks!